# TypeError in this array addition recursive problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

This function has to add all the constants in the array recursively using JavaScript. Any idea why I'm getting a type error in this recursion function?

```js
const slowAdd = (array) => {
  if (array.length === 0) return 0;

  const restOfArray = array.slice(1);

  return array[0] + slowAdd(array[restOfArray]);
}

const dataArray = [2, 5, 7]
slowAdd(dataArray);
```

Same Problem with using helper function:

```js
const fastSum = (array) => {
  return _fastSum(array, 0);
};

const _fastSum = (array, start) => {
  if (start === array.length) return 0;

  return array[start] + _fastSum(array, start + 1);
}

const dataArray = [2, 5, 7]
console.log(fastSum(dataArray));
```

Why does the `fastSum` recursion work, but the first doesn't.

Comment: `array[restOfArray]` is *a single number*, not a different array. EDIT: OK, actually `restOfArray` *is* the rest of the array. I misread it and thought it was just an index. At any rate `array[restOfArray]` certainly doesn't produce another array and `slowAdd` does expect an array

Comment: @VLAZ It will not even give a number. It will return `undefined`

Comment: @MaheerAli indeed. I initially misread the code and thought `restOfArray` would be an index. However, when it's *an array*, then most of the time it's going to produce `undefined` as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`restOfArray` is itself an array and you are trying to use it as index of another array. `array[restOfArray]` will always return `undefined`.

you should pass `restOfArray` instead of `array[restOfArray]`

```js
const slowAdd = (array)=>{
    
    if(array.length === 0) return 0;

    const restOfArray = array.slice(1);

    return array[0] + slowAdd(restOfArray);

}

const dataArray = [2, 5, 7]
console.log(slowAdd(dataArray));

//Same Problem with this one.

const fastSum = (array)=>{
    return _fastSum(array, 0);
};
const _fastSum = (array, start)=>{
    if(start === array.length) return 0;

    return array[start] + _fastSum(array, start + 1);

}

console.log(fastSum(dataArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

restOfArray is array

```
const slowAdd = (array) => {
  if (array.length === 0) return 0;

  const restOfArray = array.slice(1);

  return array[0] + slowAdd(restOfArray);
}

const dataArray = [2, 5, 7]
slowAdd(dataArray);
```